# Is there any reason to use string.Format() with just a string parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm currently updating some old code at work. I ran into a number of lines where string.Format() is used for seemingly no reason. I'm wondering if there is some use for using string.Format() without additional parameters, but I can't think of any.

What's the difference between this:

```cs
string query = String.Format(@"select type_cd, type_shpmt from codes");
```

and this:

```cs
string query = "select type_cd, type_shpmt from codes";
```

---

I also don't think that the `@` is needed since it doesn't need to be a string literal, and it's not a multi-line string.

Comment: Short answer : no

Comment: There isn't any. Someone didn't proofread their code after writing it.

Comment: What about where it is used for a reason. What is that reason? Is the original author concatenating parameter values to the sql statements? Example: `string.Format("Select something from table where column = {0}", value1);` ? If so this is where you would focus my efforts as this exposes a sql injection vulnerability in the code.

Comment: Personally, I do `@`-verbatimize my string literals to indicate to myself that a string does _not_ need to be translated (and therefore not needed to be put into a RESX file). I have different colors for my `@` and non-`@` strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cut and paste failures. Someone didn't take the time to cleanup the code. There is no reason to use `string.Format`. Simply delete it and assign directly.

---

⚠️ **Warning** ⚠️

If the person is using the `Format` to combine parameters be wary; one should use the [SQLCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8) and [SQLParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8) class to avoid sql injection.

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing, but you were first :)

Comment: ...but *spare* `@` and make the sql multiline and *readable*: `string query = 
   @"select type_cd, 
            type_shpmt 
       from codes";`

Answer (score 4):

While `Format` should be *deleted*, spare `@` and make query being *more readable*:

```
  string query = 
     @"select type_cd, 
              type_shpmt 
         from codes";
```

If you want to modify table, field names etc. (which you can't do via *Sql Parameters*) try using *string interpolation*:

```
  string myTableName = "codes";

  ...

  string query = 
     $@"select type_cd, 
               type_shpmt 
          from {myTableName}";
```

Comment: Personally, I'd say it's more beneficial to highlight what the @ does ([verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)) as the query is already readable.